# Wrong data when loop fetch expressjs nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch

I have this code

```
const admin = await this.userRepository.findOne({ username: 'admin' });    
admin.balance -= 5000;
return await this.userRepository.save(admin).then(data => {
    return { balance: data.balance };
});
```

but it return wrong value when I make a loop funtion fetch:

```
const Test = async() => fetch('http://localhost:8843/user', {method: "POST"}).then(res=>res.json()).then(data=> console.log(data))
for(let i =0; i<10; i++) Test()
```

Init value:

> username: "admin", balance: 15000

I got result:

```
{balance: 10000}
{balance: 10000}
{balance: 10000}
{balance: 10000}
{balance: 10000}
{balance: 10000}
{balance: 5000}
{balance: 5000}
{balance: 5000}
{balance: 5000}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Test` should not be declared with `async ()` since it already returns a `Promise`, using `async` on it will make it to return a `Promise` that resolves a `Promise`.

If you want to execute `Test()` 10 times one by one, you need to `await` in the for loop.

```
const Test = () => (
  fetch('http://localhost:8843/user', {method : "POST"})
  .then(res=>res.json())
  .then(data=> console.log(data))
);

// somewhere inside a `async` function
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  await Test();
}
```

Comment: but `Test` 's PM. this is of customer. I can't edit :(

Answer (score 0):

I think in the `return` statement you need to use the `async` operator which usually will come after the `await` telling your app to only complete when the operation has completed.

Comment: is it on Controller? `async Test(){ return await this.userService.Test(); }`

Comment: You shouldn't be using `await` twice the way you are, once you use the `await` then there needs to be an `async` following it...